# Cannot access wso2is.local:port:/carbon, can access via IP:port:/carbon

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've been attempting to set up service and identity providers within wso2is. I've been following the documentation, using the 'travelocity' sample. After having configured **inbound authentication with SAML2 Web SSO** (from the following documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Adding+and+Configuring+a+Service+Provider#AddingandConfiguringaServiceProvider-SAML-SSOConfiguringinboundauthenticationwithSAML2WebSSO )

I've attempted to reconfigure the service providers, but the errors I get whenever I try and access ':/travelocity.com' from a remote workstation in Chrome are as follows;

**using** https://:8080/travelocity.com
/ Error 405 - Method Not Allowed

**using** https://wso2is.local:9443/travelocity.com 
/ "This site can’t be reached wso2is.local’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Same result without https.

**using** https://:9443/travelocity.com 
/ "Error 405 - Method Not Allowed"

**using** https://wso2is.local:8080/travelocity.com 
/ "This site can’t be reached wso2is.local’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Same result without https.

**using** http://:9443/travelocity.com
/ " sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE"

**using** http://:8080/travelocity.com
/ Returns apache's default 404 page.

I'm looking for suggestions or advice, as this my first attempt at configuring a wso2is enviroment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using https://:8080/travelocity.com / Error 405 - Method Not Allowed

This occurs because you havent specified the host.

Open etc/host file. add the following line and try the flow again.

> 127.0.0.1   wso2is.local

Otherwise, just try with https://localhost:8080/travelocity.com

For more information please refer 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+Single+Sign-On